# SCM Manager's scm-server service start bind error

Tags: fedora-20, scm

I perform:

```
# service scm-server start
SCM-Server will now be started
# service scm-server status
SCM-Server is running
 PID: 2166
 PID: 2167
```

After a few seconds:

```
# service scm-server status
SCM-Server is not running
```

`/opt/scm-server/var/log/scm-server.err` contains:

```
2015-06-11 11:05:07.934:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED \
  SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    ... stack trace ...
2015-06-11 11:05:07.936:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED \
   org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@449628c3: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    ... stack trace ...
Cannot load daemon
Service exit with a return value of 3
```

`/opt/scm-server/conf/server-config.xml` contains:

```
<SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8082" />
```

Port `8082` isn't occupied:

```
# netstat -tulpn | egrep '(PID|80)' | sort
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      1190/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8015          :::*                    LISTEN      680/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8009                 :::*                    LISTEN      869/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8019                 :::*                    LISTEN      680/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      680/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8081                 :::*                    LISTEN      869/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8088                 :::*                    LISTEN      1190/java
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      602/httpd
```

If I stop the service on `8080` `scm-server` starts succesfully. Why does it try to take the default port `8080` regardless of the different config setting?